# Помогите составить регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Ребят помогите составить регулярное выражение. В общем есть:

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/<img src="\/pic\/name.gif">/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '88';
$content[$i]=preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content[$i]);
```

Суть в том, что в `<img src="\/pic\/name.gif">` имя изображение может быть любым, нужно составить регулярное выражение которое бы делало замену картинки на текст.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно заменить полностью весь тег img, то достаточно такого кода:

```
$content[$i]=preg_replace('/<img[^>]+\>/i', '88', $content[$i]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, но так не нужно, для моего примера. Так как у меня замена еще и других идет строк

Comment: Вынесите их в переменные как в вопросе, суть регулярки я правильно понял или нет?

Comment: Да, я уже так и сделал, но есть небольшая проблема. Дело в том, что у меня несколько замен. И обе нужно заменить на определенное число. Но тут есть еще одно но, то картинки подставляются рандомно. Картинка может быть как первой, второй, третьей так и четвертой. А меняет все первая регулярка на число что выше писал. А второе число не меняется. И вот сейчас я в ступоре как это можно реализовать....

Comment: @keaks88 preg_match_all вытянуть все картинки и каждую по очереди заменить на нужное число.

Comment: Не получится так как источник картинки рандомно каждый раз выдает. Она на любом месте может быть. Изза этого при замене мной числа стоят не там где нужно